# How to set selected item on page load the first time

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm working on a test project using angular where I need to select a branch and as soon as I select it, graphics will load with the selected branch's information.
When the page loads the first time, I wanted the select to come pre-selected with the item coming from the api, but whenever the page loads the first time, it gives an error and only loads some data if I manually select some branch.

[image: Branches to select]

I can set the value in the select using `[value]='selectedOption'`

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field style="margin-top: 25px;align-items: right" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Selecione uma Filial</mat-label>
  <mat-select [value]='selectedOption' (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let select of selectedAll" [value]="select.id">{{select.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

COMPONENT.TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);
import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { AccountService } from '../account/shared/account.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-charts',
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./charts.component.scss'],
})
export class ChartsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('changeEl', { static: false }) changeEl?: MatSelect;
  public selectItemBranch?: Observable<any>;
  itemBranch: any = [];
  itemsEvents: any = [];
  itemsDrivers: any = [];
  itemsAssets: any = [];
  selectedOption: any;

  @Output() newItemBranchEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  selectedAll: any = [];
  public selectedBranch: any;
  selected: any = [];


  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: 'y',

  };

  onSelectionChange(itemBranch: any) {
    this.itemsAssets = []
    this.itemsDrivers = []
    this.itemsEvents = []
    this.selectItemBranch = itemBranch.value;
    console.log(this.selectItemBranch);
  }

  seeMeBranch() {
    this.selected = this.accountService.meBranch().subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.selectedAll = resp;
        this.selectedBranch = this.selectedAll.id
        this.selectedOption = this.selectedAll[0].id
        console.log(this.selectedOption)
      });

  }

  addItemEvents(event: any) {
    this.itemsEvents = event;
  }

  filterBranch(name: string) {
    let arr = this.selectedAll.filter(
      (branch: any) => branch.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0
    );

    return arr.length ? arr : [{ name: 'No Item found' }];
  }

  addItemDrivers(event: any) {
    this.itemsDrivers = event;
  }

  addItemAssets(event: any) {
    this.itemsAssets = event;
  }

  addItemBranch(event: any) {
    this.itemBranch = event;
  }

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.selectedOption)
    this.seeMeBranch();
    console.log(this.selectedBranch)


  }
}
```

After setting the `selectedOption` in `mat-select`, it does not load the data because it comes undefined:

[image: Undefined Error]

> Error: {"timestamp":"2023-05- 11T21:21:09.099+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/api/events/quantity/branch/undefined"}

I'm calling `seeMeBranch` in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.seeMeBranch();
}
```

But when I click on any other branch of mat-select the data appears normally:

[image: graphics appear]

Comment: This makes sense because it's not defined before you load data from the api. Without seeing the code is not possible to help you here. You should include the whole code here, specially for your component.

Comment: I add the entire code of my component to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As the call is async try this approach using two way binding `[(value)]="selectedOption"`. It would be better to debug if you provide a working stackblitz

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-top: 25px;align-items: right" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Selecione uma Filial</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedOption" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let select of selectedAll" [value]="select.id">{{select.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
seeMeBranch() {
  this.selected = this.accountService.meBranch().subscribe(
    resp => {
      this.selectedAll = resp;
      this.selectedBranch = this.selectedAll.id;
      this.selectedOption = this.selectedAll[0].id; 
      console.log(this.selectedOption);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[value]='selectedOption | async'
```